# Transpose table CSS grid

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid, transpose

I have tabular data that is many columns wide and a couple of rows short, which works great on a desktop screen, but is too wide for mobile screens.  How do I make this "table" responsive - transpose it - so that it is narrow and tall on mobile screens?  I can't find clear explanation on the Internet. It is made of divs.

Comment: If you've got tabular data, you should be using an HTML table. It's still possible to transpose your table using CSS grid similar to how you do in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like this with CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
    
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
    
/* make table 'portait' instead of 'landscape' */
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 30px);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>PRODUCT</div>
  <div>APPLE</div>
  <div>MANGO</div>
  <div>ORANGE</div>
  <div>BANANA</div>
    
  <div>Price</div>
  <div>$50</div>
  <div>$25</div>
  <div>$30</div>
  <div>$15</div>
    
  <div>Quantity</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>
```